# Jquery localStorage not firing at first click

Tags: jquery, html, local-storage

When I click the   `print-receipt` I want to change the class of child div to `receipt_finished`. 
Then I replace the `localStorage` item with the new html content (containing the `receipt_finished` class).

HTML

```
<div id="1" class="print-receipt no-print page-break printed">
    <div class="receipt_content"><span>1</span></div>
    </div>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).on('click', '.print-receipt', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var receipt_id = $(this).attr('id');
            var receipt_html = $(this).html();
            $(this).find('.receipt_content').toggleClass("receipt_finished");
            localStorage.setItem('printer_' + printer_id + '_receipt_' + receipt_id, receipt_html);
            });
```

When I first refresh the page the toggleClass works fine, but the `localStorage.setItem` works only on the **second click**.
So the code works as follows:

**First div click:**

In `html` it changes to  `<div class="receipt_content receipt_finished">`

In `localStorage` nothing happens

**On the second click:**

In `html` it changes to `<div class="receipt_content">`

In `localStorage` it changes to `<div class="receipt_content receipt_finished">`

The item already exists in localStorage when the page loads or is created before this click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of toggling the class and getting the html so when you get the html it includes the class change

```
$(document).on('click', '.print-receipt', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var receipt_id = $(this).attr('id');
  // toggle the class first
  $(this).find('.receipt_content').toggleClass("receipt_finished");
  // html will now have the class change
  var receipt_html = $(this).html();

  localStorage.setItem('printer_' + printer_id + '_receipt_' + receipt_id, receipt_html);
});
```

Comment: Thank you ! That works, for some reason I didn't see that :((((((((((